# How to launch default file manager with mime type filtering - while not being interested in picked file?

Tags: java, android

From my app, I want to launch a default file manager that will filter content based on mime type that I provide. **I am not interested in the eventual user-selected file, i.e. I don't want the file content or control to be returned back to my app. Instead, I want the file manager to show default choices once the file is selected.**

I wasn't able to find any documentation or code samples that would achieve such a thing.

Obviously, these are not intents with actions:

```
Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
```

Comment: Not possible. No app will listen to a mime type specification.